# Conditional Required Fields validation is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validation-engine

I've got a new enigma for you to solve, because I can't manage to get this working.

Imagine yourself working for an online marketing company with a proprietary platform to host and manage campaigns. And then imagine only being able to validate required fields that 'just are there'. And at last; imagine a client that needs form fields to be required after a certain radio button is checked. Right? Right! Well.... no... not right.

Here is the thing. That same radio button triggers a jQuery script that eases in the 5 `div`'s with form fields that are hidden `display: block`. I have the `jQuery.validation.js` plugin at the ready.

I insert this piece of code to the form fields that are required if it meets the condition that the depending field is checked:

```
class="textInput1 validate[condRequired[radiobuttonX]]"
```

`textInput1` is a CSS class that styles an input field.

As a `submitbutton` I use an image which uses this code to submit: `input type="image"`

```
onclick="document.forms['formName'].submit();"
```

I have got:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

in place and in my head I have the link to the validation script:

```
<script src="../path/to/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
```

I use the: [Inline Form Validation Engine 2.6.2, jQuery plugin](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/)

How do I make form field Y required when `radiobuttonX` is ticked? I definitely need syntax as well, because I'm a dumbs ;-)

Comment: Can you switch to jquery-validate.js? It has a `depends:` option that can be used for this. See http://blog.adrianlawley.com/jquery-validation-rules-depends/

Comment: Would my script look anything like this then? $("#formName").validate({
rules: {
formFieldY: {
depends: function(element) {
if ($('#radiobuttonX').is(':checked')){
return true;
}else{
return false;
}
}
}
}
});

Comment: Essentially right, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can switch fromjQuery Validation Engine to jQuery-Validate, this would be the solution:

```
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        fieldY: {
            required: {
                depends: function() {
                    return $("#radioButtonX").is(":checked");
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you take a look at this fiddle? [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jazperader/k5x3n/2/), what am I missing?

Comment: I can't figure out why it's not working. I thought it might be because you used `id` rather than `name` in your form field, but I fixed that. You were also loading two copies of the plugin (minified and non-minified), but fixing that didn't help.

Comment: I'm going to implement it in a few hours... I'll keep you posted! Thnx for your time and effort, man.... much appreciated!

Comment: I updated the fiddle [JSFiddle] http://jsfiddle.net/jazperader/k5x3n/27/ - I get CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Comment: I got the same thing when I tried tweaking your fiddle. Like I said, I don't know why.